# How Would I Alter This Javascript Code to validate the data

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events

What would I need to add in order for this to validate according to how many checkboxes have been selected? I want the user to select at least two checkboxes before submission of data. Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    if (
    theForm.Conservatives.checked == false &&
    theForm.Labour.checked == false &&
    theForm.LiberalDemocrats.checked == false) 
    {
        alert ('Choose At Least Two Parties Who Will Be Standing For This Election');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}

</script>
```

The current Javascript code only validates if any checkboxes have been selected or not, but I want it to validate for two checkboxes.

Comment: Any objection to using jQuery here? Not advocating, just wondering, as it will simplify the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count how many are checked and see if it's less than 2.

```
function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    var cnt = 0;
    if (theForm.Conservatives.checked) ++cnt;
    if (theForm.Labour.checked) ++cnt;
    if (theForm.LiberalDemocrats.checked) ++cnt;
    if (cnt < 2) {
        alert ('Choose At Least Two Parties Who Will Be Standing For This Election');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're only worried about those three checkboxes and you don't want to use a JavaScript library, the easiest thing I can think of would be:

```
var checkedBoxes = [];

if(theForm.Conservatives.checked) 
    checkedBoxes.push(theForm.Conservatives);
if(theForm.Labour.checked)
    checkedBoxes.push(theForm.Labour);
if(theForm.LiberalDemocrats.checked)
    checkedBoxes.push(theForm.LiberalDemocrats;

// two or more boxes are checked
if(checkedBoxes.length < 2){
    alert('Choose at least two parties.');
}
else {
    // Do stuff with checkedBoxes.
}
```

This method will not only give you the Count of the number of checked items but will also allow you to access only the checked boxes later in your code if needed.

Comment: You meant "if (checkBoxes.length < 2)"

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (theForm.Conservatives.checked +
    theForm.Labour.checked +
    theForm.LiberalDemocrats.checked) < 2)
{
 alert ('Choose At Least Two Parties Who Will Be Standing For This Election');
 return false;
} else {    
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
  var opts = ["Conservatives","Labour","LiberalDemocrats"],
      selected = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    if (theForm[opts[i]].checked)
      selected++;
  }
  if (selected < 2) {
    alert ('Choose At Least Two Parties Who Will Be Standing For This Election');
    return false;
  } else {    
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
 if(theForm.Conservatives.checked + theForm.Labour.checked + theForm.LiberalDemocrats.checked > 1)return true;
 alert ('Choose At Least Two Parties Who Will Be Standing For This Election');
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    var checkboxes = [theForm.Conservatives, theForm.Labour, theForm.LiberalDemocrats];
    var checked = 0;
    checkboxes.forEach(function(el){ 
                              if (el.checked) checked++;
                       });
    if (checked < 2) 
    {
        alert ('Choose At Least Two Parties Who Will Be Standing For This Election');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}
```